# How to get x labels from time (time-series)

Tags: r

I am trying to format my x axis.

Say I want to get "MM.YYYY" for every value in x axis in order to use it in `axis()`, so I:

```
> test <- ts (c(12,23,45,31,15), start=2012, frequency = 12)

> time(test)
      Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May
2012 2012.000 2012.083 2012.167 2012.250 2012.333
```

My question is, how to convert from say "2012.333" to "05.2012".
I tried with:

```
> strftime(strptime(time(test),"%?.%?"),"%m.%Y")
```

but I ignore the appropriate variables in "%?.%?"

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
> library(zoo)
> format(as.yearmon(time(test)), "%m.%Y")
[1] "01.2012" "02.2012" "03.2012" "04.2012" "05.2012"
```

Comment: @user1907158 If this is a good answer, please click on the tick mark by the question, which will turn green to indicate the answer has been accepted.